# Closing ":|_|" marks, multiple "goto" | functions creation (cmd | .bat)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

How to make ,accessible trough shortcuts ("goto |anyth|" | "call |anyth|" | ..) from "for" loop ,scripts, within 1 script file

My tries:

```
for /F %%a in ("t1") do (
    if "%%a"=="" (
            call :fsc
    ) else (
        echo "n t"
        if "%%a"=="t1" (
            call :fsc
        ) else (
            call :fsc1
        )
    )
    :fsc
    echo t1
    rem how? to end the :fsc (without the addition it continuing to "pause")
    rem  (answer: not possible in bash, this example's way can't be used because "goto" breaks out ?all scopes)
    :fsc
    echo t2
)

pause
```

and other one

```
for /F %%a in ("t1") do (
    if "%%a"=="" (
            call :fsc
    ) else (
        echo "n t"
        if "%%a"=="t1" (
            call :fsc
        ) else (
            call :fsc1
        )
    )
)
:fsc
echo t1
goto :eof
:fsc1
echo t2
goto :eof

::why? after the "for" ends, execution doesn't coming here
:: (answer: all after "for" executed( including "goto :eof"))
pause
```

mintextlimitmintextlimitmintextlimitmintextlimitm

Comment: Do not use labels and `::`-stype comments in parenthesised code blocks! And note that [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) does not behave the same way as [`goto`](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)...

Comment: @aschipfl, yeah, you right, sorry, but the questions relevant, its just mistake of inserting them into this post, as for me from the code comments its pretty obvious that i know how "goto","call" works

Comment: You can use `GOTO :EOF` at the end of your called functions to return program control back to the line of code that called the function.

Comment: @Squashman, that i thought so, but it doesn't looks working, im trying to use it with 2nd example and it ending whole file's script

Comment: Ilia, you said you knew how `Call` works, but you're not using it correctly, for the reason already given to you. I would suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50818982/edit) and properly explain the task, the actual input and expected output. _Extensive comment sections highlight only that your question is lacking in detail_.

Comment: @Squashman, damn, i made mistake in the comment, in 2nd example goto works fine, also problem is in that if if i'm adding ":eof" after the "for" finishes it doesn't executing "pause" ,thats thing i do not understand

Comment: Your functions have to be the LAST code in your script.  Otherwise you need to use a GOTO to skip over them.  There should be a GOTO :EOF placed before the first label of your functions as well.

Comment: @Squashman, y, thanks, i realized it right before your post :) , as i wrote in answer ,the question still unanswered, would answer on it be: Not possible; ?

Comment: You can't put the called function within the `FOR` command.  It will execute twice then.  You have to work within the construct of the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to put your called functions at the end of your script.  Which is kind of opposite of what most people do in other scripting languages.  Functions are functions in other scripting languages but they don't work that way in batch files.  So in batch-files the best practice is to put them at the end of your script.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /F %%a in ("t1") do (
    if "%%a"=="" (
            call :fsc
    ) else (
        echo "n t"
        if "%%a"=="t1" (
            call :fsc
        ) else (
            call :fsc1
        )
    )
)
REM Put the main programming code here.
pause

REM END OF SCRIPT. ONLY FUNCTIONS BELOW.
GOTO :EOF
:fsc
echo t1
goto :eof

:fsc1
echo t2
goto :eof
```

Comment: Technically it was just question about possibility of defining the functions with start and end in bash, well ,not without some of negligence from my side :)